# vs code the window terminated unexpectedly (reason 'killed' code '15')

Tags: visual-studio-code, memory, error-handling, manjaro

I'm always having issues when trying to run code on visual studio. I'm using Jupyter Notebook on VScode and this is happening when I run Python or PySpark files.

The error message is: vs code the window terminated unexpectedly (reason 'killed' code '15').

I'm using Manjaro Linux (it is quite a recent change for me), so I did not install VSCode via .deb or .rpm. I did it using snap.
I guess it has something to do with internal memory, but I really don't know what else to do about this.

Here's one example. I have this cell on jupyter notebook:

```py
# Compile the model with optimizer (RMSprop), 
# loss function (binary_crossentropy ) and error metric (accuracy)

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                loss='binary_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])


#Split train data into: 
# validation data (the first 10000 reviews in x_train) x_val, y_val
# train data (the remaining reviews in x_train )

x_val = x_train[:10000] 
y_val = y_train[:10000]

partial_x_train = x_train[10000:]
partial_y_train = y_train[10000:]

#Fit the model with partial train data and validation data 
#(check model.fit function of keras)

history = model.fit(partial_x_train,
                    partial_y_train,
                    epochs=1,
                    batch_size=5,
                    validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

The epochs I should be using is 20 and the batch_size should be 512. Everyone was able to run it in their computers (even older computers) but I can't run it any way, even reducing the epochs to 1 and batch_size to 5 (which is ridiculously small). VScode keeps crashing every time I run this cell.

I tried running it on jupyter and the kernel just dies.

Answer (score 0):

Following the issue on official github repository of VSCode: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/196057

If you run VSCode with disabled extensions and then try to update the plugins it will fix your problem for the next time that you open VSCode with the enabled plugin.

```
code --disable-extension ms-python.vscode-pylance
```